# NDEF Select command is sent even after Reader Mode is enabled with NDEF skip flag

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

We are working on POC to emulate Payment Read from Android, but upon tapping Visa and Mastercard, Android device is sending NDEF select command. How can we avoid Android device sending this command?

NDEF Select command :00A4040007D276000085010100

Tried using FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK,
Tried setNdefPushMessage(null,activity), 
Tried res/xml configuration to select only tech NfcA, NfcB,
Tried android.nfc.disable_beam_default as meta data configuration.

We have enabled the Android read mode like below

```
private static final int READER_FLAGS =
       NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B |
               NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK |
               NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS;

nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(activity, readerCallback, READER_FLAGS, new 
Bundle());
```

We don't want android reader to send the NDEF command upon tapping the card.

Answer (score 0):

enableReaderMode: Limits the NFC controller to reader mode while **provided** Activity is in the foreground. So, make sure that the calling activity is in foreground when the tag is being discovered.
Death of this activity will unset these flags applied to the NfcService.